# how to modify user data in osx with commandline

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I am trying to modify user account data in OSX 10.13.3, for e.g. GeneratedUID or UID.

with Directory Utility, we can change any value and save it. I am sure Directory Utility uses some kind of database file or plist file, and I think we can change corresponding values with command too, for example, `dscl . -change` command,  but I can't seem to find any related info for where that command should be pointed to

[image]

I assume i should use

```
dscl .    -change record_path key old_val new_val
```

but what is `record_path` here? 
does anyone know whats the name of file that Directory Utility uses? or even how to modify account guid with dscl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`record_path` is normally `/Users/<username>`

so, for example, to change the UniqueID for user "david" from 511 to 503

```
dscl . -change /Users/david UniqueID 511 503
```

and to change their PrimaryGroupID from 1000 to 1003

```
dscl . -change /Users/david PrimaryGroupID 1000 1003
```

The plist files for this information are stored here:-

```
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users
```